# How to update final associated record

Tags: mysql

I have list of `items` that are belongs to `orders`. Each `item` has `fee_percentage` field. and the sum of `items` is `total_price` in `orders` table.

What I want to achieve? 
I want to update the `fee` field of last associated items.

```
_________________________      __________________________________________
| order ID | total_price|      | id | order_id | fee_percentage |  fee  |
-------------------------      ------------------------------------------
|   334    |     425    |      |  1 |   334    |      50        |  212  |
  # The `fee` should be 213 => |  2 |   334    |      50        |  212  |
```

As you can see the sum of `items` will be 424. I want to add the remaining fee to the last item `fee`. (So the fee of item id 2 should be 213).

Any help please?

This is what I have written so far

```
UPDATE items AS i
LEFT JOIN orders AS o ON o.order_id = b.order_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT order_id, SUM(fee) AS sum_fee
    FROM items 
    GROUP BY order_id
    WHERE deleted = 0
) AS b1 ON b1.order_id = b.order_id
SET b.fee = b.fee + (o.total_price - b1.sum_fee)
WHERE b.deleted = 0;
```

I have tried to attach it to previous query or update the last_item_id in orders record but it doesn't work.

```
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT order_id, MAX(id) AS b_last_item_id
    FROM items 
    WHERE deleted = 0
    GROUP BY order_id    
) AS b1 ON b1.order_id = b.order_id
```

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   UPDATE items AS b 
    JOIN (
        SELECT MAX( i.id ) mid, o.curr_price - SUM( i.fee ) AS diff
        FROM items AS i
        INNER JOIN orders AS o ON i.order_id = o.order_id
        GROUP BY i.order_id
        ORDER BY i.order_id, i.id
    ) AS v ON b.id = v.mid
    SET b.fee = b.fee + v.diff WHERE v.diff <> 0;
```

Comment: Much much faster and accurate.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit tricky. I think the following query should work:

```
UPDATE items AS i
JOIN orders AS o ON i.order_id = o.orderID
JOIN (
   SELECT order_id, SUM(fee) AS sum_of_fees
   FROM items
   GROUP BY order_id
) AS i2 ON i2.order_id = o.orderID  
LEFT JOIN items AS i3 
   ON i3.order_id = o.orderID AND i3.id > i.id
SET i.fee = o.total_price - (sum_of_fees - i.fee)
WHERE i3.id IS NULL;
```

The derived table used calculates the sum of fees per `order_id`. Using this value we can calculate the sum of all items BUT the current item as:

```
SUM(fee) - i.fee
```

An additional `LEFT JOIN` to `items` table is needed in order to identify the record having the maximum `id` value, which is the record that is actually being updated.